# SP3485EN current consumption

Tags: uart, current-measurement, rs485, linear-regulator

I would like to size my source regulator for a circuit which contains the RS485 to UART bridge SP3485EN.
How may I know the current consumption of the SP3485EN?
Does it depend on the load?
If it is, how can I calculate it?
Datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811021609_MaxLinear-SP3485EN-L-TR_C8963.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on the load.

So you need to handle the power of the chip itself, plus the normal situation it must handle, and in addition, some arbitrary limit of abnormal situation.

So normally an RS485 would be terminated by two 120 ohm resistors, or 60 ohms. Then additional receivers on the bus add some load - the chip is specified to handle driving at least 1.5V and up to VCC into 54 ohm load, so roughly 30 to 60 milliamps.

The chip also can handle short circuit current up to 250mA, so if you want that your regulator can keep the whole system operating at 3.3V even when there is a short circuit on the output, you need a regulator that can handle at least 250mA in addition to what the whole system normally takes.

Comment: Thanks Justme. Regarding the short circuit on the output, if that event happens, should the regulator in this case provide the 250mA or it's coming from the output, as it is mentioned in figure 8 in the datasheet?

Comment: The transceiver cannot provide any current by itself, all current must be provided by the power supply it has so it must come from the regulator.